# RedisTemplate save multiple key value pairs to hash problem

Tags: java, spring, redis

I've started using RedisTemplate in a spring app. opsForHash() has a 'put' method, but it only takes three parameters. I want to save a number of key-value pairs. This is very simple to do in node, example:

```
 redis.hmset(hashId, [key1, val1, key2, val2 ...], (err, result) => {});
```

How do I do the same with RedisTemplate or StringRedisTemplate? I want to save data to a hash as I pass them, without java appending strings when serializing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the **putAll** Method:

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/HashOperations.html#putAll-H-java.util.Map-):

```
void putAll(H key, Map<? extends HK,? extends HV> m)
Set multiple hash fields to multiple values using data provided in m.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly save a map on Redis using Redis template using something like this:

```
 Map<MyObject, AnotherObject> map = new HashMap<>();

 // Get the template from a custom redis class
 RedisConfig redis = new RedisConfig();

 // Get the template
 RedisTemplate rt = redis.redisTemplate();

 // save the map.
 rt.opsForValue().multiSet(map);
```